# How to find the closest input with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, find, closest

hi this is my html code :

```
<div class="transe_row">
    <div class="litransa1" style="cursor:pointer;">Servicii programare Transa 1</div>
    <div class="litransa suma" style="cursor:pointer;"> Adauga Suma</div>
    <input type ="text"   placeholder ="adauga suma transa" style ="display:none;">
</div>
```

and this is my js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
            $(".litransa.suma").click(function() {
                 $('.litransa.suma').find(closest('input')).css("display","inline");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I just want to change the the css from the input by clicking the .listransa.suma class. Why my code doesn't work ?thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.siblings()` for finding sibling elements:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".litransa.suma").click(function () {
     $(this).siblings('input').css("display","inline")
  });
});
```

Comment: whats the different between siblings and next ?

Comment: next will work if element is immediately after current element. In case of siblings, it Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.So it may come previous or next position in case of siblings.

Answer (score 1):

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".litransa.suma").click(function () {
        $(this).next('input').css("display", "inline");//or $(this).next('input').show();
    });
});
```

---

[`this`](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) refer to the current element clicked